# If $M$,$N$, are sufaces, and $f$ is surjective, then If $M$ is connected, then $N$ is connected.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I $f$ is a surjective function from a surface $M$ to a surface $N$,  prove that

> 1) If $M$ is connected, then $N$ is connected.
>
> 2) If $M$ is compact, the $N$ is compact.

I was asking myself if, by saying that $M$ and $N$ are surfaces, that implies that $f$, $M$ and $N$ are continuous, but I don't think so, because a surface can have singularities. So I can't use the fact that if I take an open set in the image of $f$, and take its inverse, that will be an open set...

What property, then, could help me to prove what I want?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A couple of comments: First, it doesn't make sense to say that "$M$ and $N$ are continuous." Continuity is a property that applies to maps, not surfaces. Second, these two statements are definitely not true unless you _assume_ $f$ is continuous. The fact that $M$ and $N$ are surfaces is far from being sufficient to imply continuity of $f$, even if they don't have any singularities. (For a simple counterexample, you can take $M$ and $N$ to be the unit sphere, and $f$ to be the map that sends the north pole to itself, and everything else to the south pole.)

Comment: Sorry, I just realized my counterexample should have included surjectivity, since that's what you're assuming about $f$. You could instead cook up a map that stretches the closed upper hemisphere to cover the whole sphere, and maps everything else to the north pole. Or any number of other such things.

Comment: @JackLee Just to verify... If $M$ is the unit sphere, and also $N$ is the unit sphere, and taking $f$ to be the function that sends the north pole to itself and everything else to the South is not surjective, because, any other point in the sphere $N$ apart from north/south, does not come from M. If $g$ is the function that takes $M$ as the unit sphere, and $N$ are just two points, then $N$ would not even be a surface, although it is a surjective function.

Comment: Yes, I gave a better counterexample in my second comment. Ignore the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is true for continuous map between topological spaces : the image of a connected space is connected, the image of a compact space is compact.

For example, assume that $N$ is disconnected. Write $N = A \sqcup B$ where $A,B$ are disjoint and open. Then, $f^{-1}(A) \sqcup f^{-1}(B)$ disconnect $M$. This shows that if $M$ is connected, then $N$ is connected. Compactness is similar.

Comment: I agree that that would be the proof when f is continuous (i edited my question). And that if $f$ is continuous, $M$ compact implies $N$ compact, but I've just been told that $f$ is onto, and so I am not sure that I can take an open set in the image of $f$, and know that it's inverse is also an open set

Comment: It is false if $f$ is not continuous, I can give you example if you want. Also, what is your definition of surfaces ?

Comment: I need to go to sleep so let met give you a counter-example which will show that you need $f$ to be continuous. Consider a surface $M$, and take two open $U \sqcup V \subset M$. Pick a point $v \in V$. Now define $f(x) = x$ if $x \in U \sqcup V$, $f(x) = v$ else. This map is a surjection $M \to U \sqcup V$ but the image is not connected. Small modifications gives you that both surfaces are compact if you want.

Comment: A surface in $\Bbb{R}^3$ is a subset $M$ of $\Bbb{R}^3$ such that for each point $p$ of $M$ there exists a proper patch in $M$ whose image contains a neighbor-hood of $p$ in $M$. So alright, $M$, and $N$ are continuous, because that is what  a patch is, a continuous function. Although it doesn't mean $f$ is continuous. But I will examine this counter-example.Thanks